# Storing incorrect passwords on .txt file - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am creating a python program which stores it in a list, then records in a text file called wrongpasswords.txt.

The program should ask the user for input by saying 'Please enter your password: '. The correct password will always be 'rusty' but the user can of course enter any String. And also, how do I add to my program that the number of characters the user inputs wrong is also stored for each incorrect password?

Please do mind me as I am a beginner in programming and python.

Please see my code below:

```
enteredPass = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
incorrectPass= file("wrongpasswords.txt","w")                      
counter = 0

for i in range(0, counter+1):

    if enteredPass != "rusty":
        counter = counter +1
        incorrectPassO = open("wrongpasswords.txt","w")
        incorrectPassO.write("Incorrect password" +str(counter)+": " + enteredPass + "\n")
        incorrectPassO.close()
        enteredPass = raw_input("Enter your password: ")


    else:
        incorrectPassO = open("wrongpasswords.txt","w")

        incorrectPassO.write("Correct password entered on the " + str(counter)+"th entry")
        incorrectPassO.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you're trying to create a simple login program that counts the wrong login attempts? This should work:

```
counter = 0
correct_answer_entered = False

while not correct_answer_entered:
    enteredPass = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
    counter = counter + 1

    if enteredPass != "rusty":
        incorrectPassO = open("wrongpasswords.txt","a")
        incorrectPassO.write("Incorrect password" +str(counter)+": " + enteredPass + "\n")
        incorrectPassO.close()

    else:
        incorrectPassO = open("wrongpasswords.txt","a")
        incorrectPassO.write("Correct password entered on the " + str(counter)+"th entry")
        incorrectPassO.close()
        correct_answer_entered = True
```

The points I fixed in your code that you should notice:

- I replaced the "w" with an "a" where you open the file, since "w" makes it write over what's already wroten in the file, while "a" appends after what's there.
- I replaced the for loop with a while, what you did was a range from 0 to 1, so the loop would exit after the first round, I added a boolean value (correct_answer_entered), to indicate if the correct password was entered, and keeps going if it wasn't.
- I moved the "counter = counter + 1" outside of the if statement, since the number of attempts is not related to wither the password is correct or not, the way you did it if the password was correct at the first attempt it'd say 0th attempt instead of 1th.

overrall your code is pretty nice and it's good to see new people getting into programming ^.^

Comment: I am trying to learn slowly but surely. Thank you so much for your help and assistance! It is working fine now :D

Comment: Glad I could help ^.^ Just make sure you understand the changes and not just putting them there ;)